# No session IQ response from the google talk server using XMPP

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I am trying to mimic the XMPP stream to connect to the google talk servers.
I am however facing a problem when sending the session IQ:

**The problem: I don't receive a response from the server in any way after sending this:**

```
<iq id="skcevhxmpp_ceschool@gmail.com_6" type="set" to="gmail.com"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session" /></iq>
```

This is the complete flow:

```
<stream:stream to='gmail.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>**
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="7FB5653900A7A245" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>

<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" />
<proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>

<stream:stream to='gmail.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="508024A63664BA3D" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>

<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="PLAIN">{Valid auth token}</auth>
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>

<stream:stream to='gmail.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="A407B98F76E98F73" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
<stream:features><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>

<iq id="skcevhxmpp_ceschool@gmail.com_5" type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>xmpp</resource></bind></iq>
<iq id="skcevhxmpp_ceschool@gmail.com_5" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>ceschool@gmail.com/xmppFC762B4C</jid></bind></iq>

<iq id="skcevhxmpp_ceschool@gmail.com_6" type="set" to="gmail.com"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session" /></iq>
```

Extra information:

- I use the PLAIN authentication (see:
  https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/rawxmpp)
- I start using the SslStream after I receive the proceed ... xmpp tls
- I use the google talk server to send the xmpp messages to (talk.google.com)

The expected response would be something like:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="gmail.com" type="result" id="skcevhxmpp_ceschool@gmail.com_6" />
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

try to send the session iq without the to attribute.

```
<iq id="abcd" type="set">
  <session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session" />
</iq>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it without the to attribute, but still the same problem.